# How to deduce $P(C|E) \leq P(C)$ from the following equation

Tags: probability, inequality, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

From the below equation:

$$P(C|E) = {P(Q) \cdot P(C) \over P(Q) \cdot P(C) + (1 - P(C))} $$

where $Q$ is $E|C$.

How could you deduce the following inequality?
$$ P(C|E) \leq P(C) $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Well, the "below equation" is not exactly the Bayes' formula. Do you mean to ask "provided that the below equation holds, prove $P(C\mid E)\le P(C)$"? Also, what would the *correct* Bayes' formula look like, and how does it differ from the "below equation" and does that help you solve the problem?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Right. I want to deduce the equality from the equation provided. It is not Bayes Equation, but the equation provided above was formed on top of the Bayes equation. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: It is quite easy to see that the right hand side of the given inequality is at most $P(C)$.  Please show your attempt.